# Can't override board_vendor (USB manufacturer) via platformio.ini

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, usb, avr, platformio

I want to override the `USB_PRODUCT` and `USB_MANUFACTURER` strings on my Sparkfun Pro Micro.

According to the docs (http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/atmelavr/sparkfun_promicro16.html#configuration), I can

> override default SparkFun Pro Micro 5V/16MHz settings per build environment using `board_***` option

The Pro Micro's [board settings json](https://github.com/platformio/platform-atmelavr/blob/master/boards/sparkfun_promicro16.json) have the `build.usb_product` and `vendor` fields (defaults are `SparkFun Pro Micro` and `SparkFun`).

I can override the `USB_PRODUCT` with this `platformio.ini`:

```
[env:sparkfun_promicro16]
platform = atmelavr
board = sparkfun_promicro16
framework = arduino
board_build.usb_product = "MyProduct"
board_vendor = "MyCompany"
```

The correct defines will show up in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
...
        "defines": [
            "PLATFORMIO=30602",
            "ARDUINO_AVR_PROMICRO16",
            "F_CPU=16000000L",
            "ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR",
            "ARDUINO=10805",
            "USB_VID=0x1B4F",
            "USB_PID=0x9203",
            "USB_PRODUCT=\"MyProduct\"",
            "USB_MANUFACTURER=\"MyCompany\"",
            "__AVR_ATmega32U4__",
            ""
        ],
...
```

But as `dmesg` shows, only `USB_PRODUCT` is applied, not `USB_MANUFACTURER`:

```
[119019.190230] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 115 using xhci_hcd
[119019.344882] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b4f, idProduct=9203, bcdDevice= 1.00
[119019.344888] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[119019.344892] usb 1-1: Product: MyProduct
[119019.344896] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SparkFun
[119019.346978] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

The relevant code is at https://github.com/platformio/platform-atmelavr/blob/master/builder/frameworks/arduino.py#L40.
It looks like the `build_vendor` setting should work?

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use correct #define : USB_MANUFACTURER_STRING and USB_PRODUCT_STRING

```
On platformio.ini :
    -D USBD_VID=0x0483
    -D USBD_PID=0x5740
    -D USB_MANUFACTURER_STRING="\"YOURNAME\""
    -D USB_PRODUCT_STRING="\"BLUEPILL_F401CCU6\""
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

platformio.ini:

```
[env:adafruit_neotrinkey_m0]
platform = atmelsam
board = adafruit_neotrinkey_m0
...
extra_scripts = pre:setUSB.py
```

setUSB.py:

```
Import("env")
board_config = env.BoardConfig()
board_config.update("build.hwids", [
  ["0x27B8", "0x01ED"]
])
board_config.update("build.usb_product", "NeoPixel Trinkey M0-XXX")
board_config.update("vendor", "Adafruit-X")
```

Result:

```
~: system_profiler SPUSBDataType

USB:
USB 3.1 Bus:
Host Controller Driver: AppleT6000USBXHCI

NeoPixel Trinkey M0-XXX:

Product ID: 0x01ed
Vendor ID: 0x27b8
Version: 1.00
Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
Manufacturer: Adafruit-X
Location ID: 0x02100000 / 1
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 100
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```